# Import XML into existing document while keeping format php

Tags: php, xml, import, export

I am trying to import XML data from an HTML form into a pre-existing xml document. The data gets imported but all the formatting is lost and it is imported on a single line.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
if (file_exists("{$filename}.xml")) {
  $xml -> load("{$filename}.xml");
}

$data = $xml -> getElementsByTagName("data")->item(0);

$match = $xml -> createElement("match");  
$data -> appendChild($match);

$xml -> formatOutput = true;
$data -> formatOutput = true;

$xml->save("{$filename}.xml");
```

All of the data I want to import is within `$match`. The data I want to merge it with looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <match>
    <pregame>
      <userName>Jack</userName>
      <teamNumber>4043</teamNumber>
      <matchNumber>12</matchNumber>
      <tablet>1</tablet>
    </pregame>
    <autonomous>
      <autoScore>20</autoScore>
      <autoSpy>0</autoSpy>
    </autonomous>
    <duringMatch>
      <defensive>0</defensive>
      <lowBar>0</lowBar>
      <portcullis>0</portcullis>
      <teeterTotter>2</teeterTotter>
      <moat>1</moat>
      <ramparts>0</ramparts>
      <drawbridge>1</drawbridge>
      <sallyPort>0</sallyPort>
      <rockWall>2</rockWall>
      <roughTerrain>0</roughTerrain>
      <lowGoals>10</lowGoals>
      <highGoals>1</highGoals>
    </duringMatch>
    <postGame>
      <canChallenge>1</canChallenge>
      <canScale>0</canScale>
      <allianceScore>143</allianceScore>
      <fouls>0</fouls>
      <techFouls>0</techFouls>
      <notes>Awesome!</notes>
    </postGame>
  </match>
</data>
```

Is there a way to import it between the `<data>` tags and after the `</match>` tag and still keep the formatting?

*edit*: After some more testing, I have discovered that the document is formatted fine if there is no existing tags in the document. It appears that when I load the `<data>` tag from the document, it breaks the ability to format the `$xml` document. Is there an alternative way of doing things so I can retain the format while still appending the data within the `<data>` tags of the existing document?

Comment: what is the current content of "pre-existing xml document" and how do you instantiating the `$xml` object ?

Comment: `$doc->formatOutput = true;` before save

Comment: Tried that and the result was the same.